# Laravel: Foreign key incorrectly formed

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

So I am busy with making this migration and afther a ton of research, he still gives me the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `dev`.`bindings` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `bindings` add constraint `bindings_users_id_foreign` foreign key (`users_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

Code:

```
Schema::create('bindings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('users_id');

    $table->foreign('users_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
});

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});
```

Versions:

```
PHP: v7.3
Laravel: v5.8.4
MariaDB: v10.3.13
Homestead: v8.1.0
```

As that I am aware, this should form a foreign key correctly. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: What is the data type of your `id` column in the users table?

Comment: @Script47 It's a `bigIncrement` type, also tried `Increment` but that didn't help :(
|| Edit: added it to the main post as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: as other answers stated, i did not notice it, you will need to create the users table, before the foreign key can be created.

When you do foreign keys, both fields will need to have the same properties. So in your case if you use bigIncrements your users_id needs to be an unsigned big int.

```
// User table needs to be created first
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});

Schema::create('bindings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('users_id')->unsigned();

    ...
});
```

Also the standard is to name it `user_id`, this will make it easier to do relations in `Laravel`.

Answer (score 1):

In your migration, place your parent table migration on top then child table

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
        });


Schema::create('bindings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

And then run `php artisan migrate` command.

Comment: use $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned() not users_id

Comment: The observation of users needing to be created first is totally true.

Comment: In the actual migration, it would have to be before - it's likely changed places in the question as the `users` table was only added after the question was originally asked. If the `users` table didn't exist before trying to add the FK, you would get a different error. The answer also uses `unsignedBigInteger()`, which is not necessarily correct. Later versions require `bigInteger->unsigned()`